# Highcharts plotLine between two points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The red line is `yAxis.plotLines`, the green one is what i want.
Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminroosta/j6okyvf1/).

[image]

**Update:**
Found a hack ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminroosta/f3n3d5za/)) by creating a custom symbol. The downside are:
1- I'll loose the symbol for one the points.
2- Not sure how move to it up/down dynamically.

```
     chart.series[0].data[2].update({ 
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'red',
      lineWidth:4,
      lineHeight: 25,
      radius: 50,
      lineColor:'orange',
      symbol: 'hline'
    }
});
```

Comment: You can try using renderer but i doubt you can achieve using it, rather as an alternative solution you can handle it by creating one extra series on the chart.

Comment: why don't yo simply calculate the mean of the values between whom you want the plot line.

note: plot lines always run through the length/breadth of the chart. if you don't want it in such a way you can go with @TechnoCrat comment

Comment: @TechnoCrat Adding a new Series is a good solution, Thanks. (BTW i've updated the question, what do you think about custom symbols?)

Comment: Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/vhwnpead/
It shows how to create and update a line (defined as a series).

Comment: @AminRoosta I didn't get 1st point, can you elaborate more on it, for 2nd point moving it up/down dynamically, you can use solution kamil's solution.